# How can I open root access in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, private

How can I open the root directory in an iPhone?

I know messages saved in `sms.db`, that is in "/var/root/Library/SMS/sms.db", but I can not see sub folders of root. I know, the root has a password and it should be entered to open, but how can open this without unlock or entering a password?

Answer (score 7):

This is locked away, so you can't access it without jailbreaking.

Comment: Hello Alex, I am new at iPhone. My device is jailbreak. I am developing jailbreak application. Still after jailbreak, I can't access sms.db file. It's needed root permission. How can I give a root permission ? please help me. Many Thanks.